# Fetch Last Friday of Month & Next Sunday

Tags: bash, calendar

I want to find some information between two dates (Last Friday of Month and it's successive Sunday).

For now, I'm adding all the dates(formatted as `mm/dd/yy`) in a file `dates_file.in` like this:

```
05/29/20,05/31/20
06/26/20,06/28/20
07/31/20,08/02/20
```

and running a `for` loop like this

```
for dates in `cat dates_file.in`
do
date1=`echo $dates | cut -d',' -f1`
date2=`echo $dates | cut -d',' -f2`
xyz_cmd -start="$date1" -end="$date2" -report_parms
done
```

Is there a way I can use `calendar` to fetch the dates or export the dates to `dates_file.in`
file?

OS is RHEL 6.5

Comment: What is the expected output for the sample input?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin , I want to use Calendar (or any other inbuild commnd) to get the `Last Friday of Month` + `Next Successive Sunday`, like the dates shown in `dates_file.in`

Answer (score 1):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and GNU [date](/questions/tagged/date):

```sh
# a function to return a positive number for "x % y"
# e.g.  `floorMod -1 7` outputs: 6
floorMod() { local num=$1 div=$2; echo $(( ((num % div) + div) % div )); }

formatDate() { local y=$1 m=$2 d=$3 delta=$4; date -d "$y-$m-$d $delta" "+%m/%d/%y"; }

year=2020
for month in {1..12}; do
    # get the last day of this month, and its day of the week
    read -r day dow < <(date -d "$year-$month-01 + 1 month - 1 day" "+%d %w")

    # decrement until we find Friday
    until ((dow == 5)); do
        ((day--))
        dow=$(floorMod $((dow - 1)) 7)
    done

    start=$(formatDate $year $month $day)
    end=$(formatDate $year $month $day "+2 days")
    echo "$start $end"
done
```

```
01/31/20 02/02/20
02/28/20 03/01/20
03/27/20 03/29/20
04/24/20 04/26/20
05/29/20 05/31/20
06/26/20 06/28/20
07/31/20 08/02/20
08/28/20 08/30/20
09/25/20 09/27/20
10/30/20 11/01/20
11/27/20 11/29/20
12/25/20 12/27/20
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, using `cal` here.

```
cat script.ksh
month="$1"
year="$2"
####To get current month's Friday.
cal "$month" "$year" 2>/dev/null |
tac |
awk '
NF>=6{
  print "current month last Friday is:"$(NF-1)" and Sunday is:"$NF
  exit
}
'
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfill my needs, it does get the Last Friday of Month, but I don't need the 1st Sunday of Next Month, I need the Successive Sunday following the Last Friday of Month.

Comment: @Marcos, ok I have edited my solution now, could you please do check the same and let me know then?